# Trying to run JavaScript from Python

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x

I am trying to run the below script from Python.

```
import execjs
var request = require('request');

var apiHostName='https:/url.com';

emailAddress = 'my.email@company.com'
apiKey = 'api_key'

function callback(error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log("Identity with email address " + emailAddress + " found:");
    var b= JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("id="+b.identityId+",api key="+b.apiKey+",type="+b.type);
  } else{
    if (response.statusCode == 401) {
      console.log ("Couldn't recognize api key="+apiKey);
    } else if (response.statusCode == 403) {
      console.log ("Operation forbidden for api key="+apiKey);
    } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
      console.log ("Email address " +emailAddress + " not found");
    }
  }
}
```

I did this:

```
pip install py-mini-racer
pip install PyExecJS
```

I would think this is pretty close, based on the research that I did, but I don't know for sure.  All I'm getting now is this error: 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'

The error occurs on this line: 'var request = require('request');'

Obviously, I am using my actual email and api key.  I am running Python 3.x.

Comment: Please provide the Python code. You'll have greater chances of getting a good response with [MRVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: It appears that you are trying to run Javascript from the Python executable, Javascript is not valid Python syntax.  You need to do much more than just `import execjs`.  Note that `PyExecJS`, according to PyPi, is no longer maintained.

Comment: Instead of going through a command-line interface I wanted to run this JS script in Python.  Can I not do that?  If not, it's totally fine.  I thought this was do-able.

Comment: The examples from [PyExecJS](https://github.com/doloopwhile/PyExecJS) explicitly call `execjs.eval` or `execjs.compile` on JS code, they don't include JS code inline mixed with the Python. So, you have to do the same thing as those examples.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're using a library, [`PyExecJS`](https://github.com/doloopwhile/PyExecJS), which claims to be both no longer maintained, and poorly designed.

So, this probably isn't the best choice in the first place.

---

Second, you're using it wrong.

The examples all include JS code as strings, which are passed to `execjs.eval` or `execjs.compile`.

You're trying to include JS code directly inline as if it were Python code. That isn't going to work; it will try to parse the JS code as Python and raise a `SyntaxError` because they aren't the same language.<sup>1</sup>

So, you have to do the same thing as the examples. That might look something like this:

```
import execjs

jscode = """
    var request = require('request');

    var apiHostName='https:/url.com';

    emailAddress = 'my.email@company.com'
    apiKey = 'api_key'

    function callback(error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log("Identity with email address " + emailAddress + " found:");
        var b= JSON.parse(body);
        console.log("id="+b.identityId+",api key="+b.apiKey+",type="+b.type);
      } else{
        if (response.statusCode == 401) {
          console.log ("Couldn't recognize api key="+apiKey);
        } else if (response.statusCode == 403) {
          console.log ("Operation forbidden for api key="+apiKey);
        } else if (response.statusCode == 404) {
          console.log ("Email address " +emailAddress + " not found");
        }
      }
    }
"""
execjs.eval(jscode)
```

Or, probably even better, move the JavaScript to a separate `.js` file, then run it like this:

```
import os.path
import execjs

dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
with open(os.path.join(dir, 'myscript.js')) as f:
    jscode = f.read()
execjs.eval(jscode)
```

---

<sub>1. Someone *could* write an import hook for Python that did something similar to perl's [`Inline::Python`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Inline-Python/Python.pod), [`Inline::Java`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java), etc. for Python, allowing you to embed code from other languages directly in your Python scripts. Periodically, someone does try to write such a thing, but they always seem to abandon it as a bad idea before it's even production-ready, or redesign it to be more like `PyExecJS`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks a lot abarnert!  When I ran the first script I got this: 'ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token var'.  When I ran the second one, which I really prefer, I got this: 'ProgramError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token import'.  Does that mean I can't pass in variables?  That's what I was hoping to do.  'emailAddress' and 'apiKey' are variables.